# Run SPSS from command line on OSX?

Tags: macos, spss

Is there a way to run SPSS from the command line on OSX?  I'm thinking it should be something like

```
./Applications/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/22/SPSSStatistics.app/Contents/MacOS/stats -i dostuff.sps
```

But I can't get it to give me a help file or find any docs onlne

Comment: Look up the *production facility*. I have [a blog post illustrating it for Windows](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/automating-tasks-in-spss-using-production-jobs/), but I imagine the command line call is similar (if not exactly the same).

Comment: That's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there looks OK. If it is failing, in a terminal window (your path may vary; I have the default here):

```
cd /Applications/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/26/SPSSStatistics.app/Contents/MacOS
../stats <arg>
```

where  is a syntax, output, or SAV file say, for example.